# How do I sum all the values placed in an array from a single JTextField by looping or otherwise to get the mean or average?

Tags: java

I'm quite new to java and wanted to ask for help. I've been trying to make a statistic calculator where it finds the mean, median, mode, maximum, and minimum of a user inputted set. I've been stuck trying to find the right command where it can read all values instead of just reading a single value for mean. Here's the code as of now:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class proto extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JTextField un, s1;
    private JButton cal;
    private JPanel p1, p2;
    private int[] unit;
    private int s1n, length;
    private double sum, mean;
    private JLabel set, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
    private String str;
    private String[] astr;

public proto() {
    setTitle("Prototype");
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    cal = new JButton("Calculate");

    s1 = new JTextField(20);
    p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    p2 = new JPanel();
    set = new JLabel("Set 1");
    r1 = new JLabel("Mean: ");
    r2 = new JLabel("Median: ");
    r3 = new JLabel("Mode: ");
    r4 = new JLabel("Minimum: ");
    r5 = new JLabel("Maximum: ");

    sum = 0;
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    p1.add(set);
    p1.add(s1);
    s1.addActionListener(this);
    p1.add(r1);
    p1.add(r2);
    p1.add(r3);
    p1.add(r4);
    p1.add(r5);
    p2.add(cal, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    cal.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent sigh) {
    if(sigh.getSource() == cal) {            
        try {
        astr = s1.getText().split(", ");
        unit = new int[astr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < astr.length; i++) {
                unit[i] = Integer.parseInt(astr[i]);
                sum =+ unit[i]; //basically sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(astr[i])
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException fk) {
            
        }
        mean = sum / astr.length;
        r1.setText("Mean: " + mean);
        System.out.println(unit);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new proto();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have an array of `int`. Do you not know how to determine the median, mode, minimum and maximum for that array? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: And your mean going to wrong way because your `sum` store only last value from array.

Comment: @ArichiPrograms - try ```sum += unit[i]``` - the other way round is effectively ```sum = unit[i]```

Comment: Thanks for the help dudes! I managed to finally get my mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your mean is not right because `sum` variable store only last value from array. A condition should be `sum += unit[i]`.

Your codition is:

```
int[] arr = {2, 5, 8, 10};
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
     sum =+ arr[i] // sum = +arr[i]
}

// sum variable store last value from from array
sum: 10
```

Condition should be:

```
int[] arr = {2, 5, 8, 10};
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
     sum += arr[i] // sum = sum + arr[i]
}

// sum variable store sum of array
sum: 25
```

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't know that the placement of symbol can affect what I'm getting.